# Retrieve a child and parent from sql table, given child or parent

Tags: sql, sql-server

Here is my table: `Test`

```
id     OrderNo   parent_id
9      111      null     
4241   111       null     
5330   111       null     
1085   111       5330     
1087   111       1085     
2643   111       1087
```

In above table there is parent child relationship.

What I want to achieve is given any id (child or parent) retrieve all the rows associated with it (whole cluster). For example in above table if we give input as `id = 1087` it should return following rows:

```
id  
5330  
1085   
1087  
2643
```

if we give parent as input example `id = 5330`:

```
id  
5330  
1085  
1087  
2643
```

How can I write a query or function which takes and Id and return all associated element in that cluster?

Comment: Can anyone help me displaying table properly ? Tried many things but could not format it

Comment: You can do this using a recursive cte. If you can post some ddl and sample data in a consumable format I can help. sqlfiddle.com is a great place to start. Otherwise just look it up in google and give it a shot yourself.

Comment: @S52 I formatted your post a bit, but for future reference you might want to look at the help for the inline editor: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: @SeanLange What do you mean by sample data in consumable format ? Do you want more data in table?

Comment: Meaning something I can run code against instead of taking this and turning it into a table. That is why I said sqlfiddle.com is a good place to start. Go there and check it out. The idea is to make it easier on the people who are helping you by making it easy on them. :D

Answer (score 1):

using this ddl:

```
CREATE TABLE orders
    (id int, OrderNo int, parent_id varchar(4))
;

INSERT INTO orders
    (id, OrderNo, parent_id)
VALUES
    (9, 111, NULL),
    (4241, 111, NULL),
    (5330, 111, NULL),
    (1085, 111, '5330'),
    (1087, 111, '1085'),
    (2643, 111, '1087')
;
```

Because you want to 'start' anywhere, you really need two recursive queries.  One to transverse your list in the deeper or 'childish' direction, and one towards the more general or 'parental' nodes.

You can try something like this

```
WITH childishCTE (orderNo, id, parent_id, [level]) as
(

    SELECT orderNo, id, parent_id, 0 as [level]
    FROM orders
-- --PUT YOUR ID HERE! --------------------------
    WHERE ID = 1087

    UNION ALL

    SELECT t.orderNo, t.id, t.parent_id, [level] + 1
        FROM orders t
            INNER JOIN childishCTE cte
                ON t.parent_id = cte.id

)
, parentalCTE as
(
    SELECT orderNo, id, parent_id, 0 as [level]
    FROM childishCTE
    WHERE Level = 0

    UNION ALL

    SELECT t.orderNo, t.id, t.parent_id, [level] - 1
        FROM orders t
            INNER JOIN parentalCTE cte
                ON t.id = cte.parent_id
)


SELECT id, level FROM childishCTE
UNION 
SELECT id, level FROM parentalCTE
ORDER BY level
```

Note that the ID you are testing doesn't go in a where clause at the end of the query.  It's going into the part of the recursive query known as the 'anchor'.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your quick reply.